# How to tell Typescript I already null-checked a variable?

Tags: typescript

Given the following (patently absurd but structurally realistic) code,

```js
function doFoo(food: string | null = null) {
  food = food ?? getFood();  // getFood: () => string | null
  if (!food) {
    throw Error("There's still no food :(");
  }
  plate[food] = true;
}
```

I get the error from TypeScript `Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)` on the line reading `plate[food] = true`.

How can I tell TypeScript that there's no way that execution can reach that line with `food` as `null`?

Comment: Reading the code, I see no issue. So I just tested your code on a playground, and it doesn't give me any error. It works... Are you sure you've done everything right? Is your `plate` object of type `{ [key: string]: boolean }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. Here is a complete demo that demonstrates zero errors:

```
declare function getFood(): string | null;
declare const plate: { [key: string]: boolean };

function doFoo(food: string | null = null) {
  food = food ?? getFood();  // getFood: () => string | null
  if (!food) {
    throw Error("There's still no food :(");
  }
  plate[food] = true; // No Error
}
```

[image]

Comment: Huh. I'll see if I can produce a minimal reproduction, and then open a question or bug or something and link it from here. Thanks.